# Excel function to return in a date based on value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this data in excel.

```
    Code              Duration Months      
    
  1  AC-26482-17              8          
  2  AC-26482-18              10         
  3
```

How can i return a start and expiration date like in this table? The last 2 digits of my code is always the starting year (01/01/....).

```
    Code              Duration Months        Start         Expiration 
    
  1  AC-26482-17              8             01/01/2017      01/08/2017
  2  AC-26482-18              10            01/01/2018      01/10/2018
  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your "Start" column you can do:

```
="01/01/"&RIGHT(A3,2)
```

For your "Expiration" column you can do:

```
=IF(LEN(B3)=1,"01/0"&B3&"/"&RIGHT(A3,2),"01/"&B3&"/"&RIGHT(A3,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

In C2, formula copied down :

```
=0+("1/"&RIGHT(A2,2))
```

In D2, formula copied down :

```
=EDATE(C2,B2-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Use the DATE function (in both answers) to avoid potential pitfalls with international date formats; never build dates using strings.

Comment: I have some rows with blanks which i like to remove blanks, what will be the modification? thanks for the help!